# Uncheck all checkboxes related to clicked button.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The problem  :**
I have checkbox groups created dynamically. If at least one checkbox is checked the title of that group is showing up in page's top in separate `div` with cross icon `x`. What I wanted to do is on clicking each added title's cross `x` it need to uncheck all checkboxes related to that title and remove title itself.

*Codepen example :* https://codepen.io/gabe747/pen/jLaEvq

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  check()
})

function check() {
  $(".col-filter_amount").text("");

  $(".col-filter_block").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length)
      $(this).find(".cols-title").clone().append('<a class="checkbox-remover" href="javascript:;">x</a>').appendTo($(".col-filter_amount"))
  })
}

$(".checkbox-remover").on('click', function() {
  //   REMOVE TITLE AND UNCHECK RELATED TO THIS TITLE CHECKBOXES
});
```

```css
.col-filter_amount {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.col-filter_amount h4 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.col-filter_amount h4 a {
  color: fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-filter_amount">

</div>

<div class="col-filter_block">
  <h4 class="cols-title" data-value="1">group1</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item4
</div>

<div class="col-filter_block">
  <h4 class="cols-title" data-value="2">group2</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item4
</div>
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Why not use a radio button? Or am I understanding the problem wrong?

Comment: For me the problem is not in checkbox or radio, but if you try out to check one you will see the title added in top, all I need is on click the top title it unchecks all checked and hide itself

Comment: Yep, you're right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its dynamically added element you need to listen for `click` event on some parent element that already exists,  `body` for example. Then you can use data attribute to select input elements with same value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  check()
});
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  check()
})

function check() {
  $(".col-filter_amount").text("");

  $(".col-filter_block").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length)
      $(this).find(".cols-title").clone().append('<a class="checkbox-remover" href="javascript:;">x</a>').appendTo($(".col-filter_amount"))
  })
}

$('body').on('click', ".checkbox-remover",  function() {
  $('input[data-value="'+$(this).parent().data('value')+'"]').attr('checked', false)
  $(this).parent().remove()
});
```

```css
.col-filter_amount {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.col-filter_amount h4 {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px;
}

.col-filter_amount h4 a {
  color: fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-filter_amount">

</div>

<div class="col-filter_block">
  <h4 class="cols-title" data-value="1">group1</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="1">item4
</div>

<div class="col-filter_block">
  <h4 class="cols-title" data-value="2">group2</h4>
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item1
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item2
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item3
  <input type="checkbox" data-value="2">item4
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you add the click handler when you add the element?

Comment: This one works, only one question can we somehow trigger clicks for those unchecked ones?

Comment: @Gabriel Manukyan  You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2156/

Comment: No Sir! everything was perfect but when removing checked somehow to trigger a click, so that the browser will understand that checkbox is unchecked and my filters will reset

Comment: I see, you could trigger custom event maybe like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2157/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox-remover', function(){
    var button = $(this).closest("h4");
    $("input[type=checkbox][data-value="+button.data("value")+"]").prop("checked",false);
    button.remove();
});
```

Added to your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zdPGOR

Comment: Short and sweet. +1

Comment: @strongLucky Can we trigger click while unchecking?

Comment: sure. On which element? add .trigger("click");

Comment: This solution helped me with a similar issue.